# Powershell get Zabbix Hosts via API

Tags: powershell, zabbix

Im trying to use powershell to get host data from the Zabbix API.

I want to get the following columns back for host groups 15, 24, 26:

- hostid
- host
- status
- interfaceid
- ip
- dns
- useip

If I use Postman to submit the query, I would submit the following which works:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "host.get",
    "params": {
        "output": [
            "hostid",
            "host",
            "status"
        ],
        "groupids": [15, 24, 26],
        "selectInterfaces": [
            "interfaceid",
            "ip",
            "dns",
            "useip"
        ]
    },
    "id": 2,
    "auth": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

So far I have the following powershell which returns a lot of information

```
$params.body = @{
    "jsonrpc"= "2.0"
    "method"= "host.get"
    "params"= @{
        output = "extend"
        selectHosts = "extend"
    }
    auth= "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    id= 2
} | ConvertTo-Json

$result = Invoke-WebRequest @params

Write-Host $result
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to request only the information I want, I've not done a powershell script like this before so would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build your `$params.body` with the same fields and options you used in Postman:

```
$params.body = @{
    "jsonrpc"= "2.0"
    "method"= "host.get"
    "params"= @{
        output = @( "host", "hostid", "status" )
        selectInterfaces = @( "interfaceid", "ip", "dns", "useip" )
        groupids = @( "15", "24", "26")
    }
    auth = xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    id = 2
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

You should get something like:

```
hostid host        status interfaces                                                                                          
------ ----        ------ ----------                                                                                          
10017  somehost    0      {@{interfaceid=30251; ip=192.168.10.15; dns=; useip=1}}                                               
10051  anotherone  0      {@{interfaceid=12353; ip=10.10.10.20; dns=tanotherone.mydomain.com; useip=1}}                       
10054  whatisthis  0      {@{interfaceid=43262; ip=172.16.1.20; dns=; useip=1}}
```

Comment: I managed to get it working just before your response, and I did the same thing, thats for the help though!!!